# How to bind an amChart (Stock Chart) to a DataTable?

Tags: c#, charts, amcharts

I've managed to bind an amChart Line Chart to a DataTable by assigning the member `DataItemsSource` of the `LineChartGraph` to `mytable.DefaultView`.

I'm trying to do the same with an amChart Stock Chart. However the `Graph` object does not have a `DataItemsSource`. It has instead a `DataSetID` member that points to a `DataSet` defined as part of the `StockChart` control. Anyways... Any suggestion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error, it turned out that you can bind ItemsSource to a DataTable. Judging by the number of responses I've gotten... it looks like not that many people use this control. It's surprising b/c it's absolutely great.. and free.

```
<ams:StockChart ... >
   ...
   <ams:StockChart.DataSets>
      <ams:DataSet ItemsSource="{Binding Table}" ... />
      ...
   </ams:StockChart.DataSets>
   ...
</ams:StockChart>
```